# How to include JSON object within JavaScript so that it can be accessed by functions?

Tags: javascript, json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [
    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
]
};

function send(myJSONObject){
    var c = document.createElement('div');
    var t = document.createTextNode(myJSONObject.bindings[1].regex);
    c.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(c);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="go" onclick="send();" />
</body>
```

---

Can I access a JSON object in the above way by directly passing JSON object into a JavaScript function and including the value of it as the value of the text node? If not what are the things I am missing out? I want the dynamically created div to have the value of the JSON object in its text node.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use the globally defined object or pass the object along with the function:

Either:

```
function send(){
    var c = document.createElement('div');
    var t = document.createTextNode(myJSONObject.bindings[1].regex);
    c.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(c);
}
```

with

```
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="send();" />
```

**OR**

```
function send(myJSONObject){
    var c = document.createElement('div');
    var t = document.createTextNode(myJSONObject.bindings[1].regex);
    c.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(c);
}
```

with

```
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="send(myJSONObject);" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are declaring a global `myJSONObject` and then declaring a function argument also called `myJSONObject`.

The global one *would* be accessible from within the function except that you are masking it with the one in the argument list. You then call `send` without passing in any object. The result being that the `myJSONObject` accessible inside the function, i.e. the one from the argument list, is `null`.

You could either remove the argument from `send` and just use the global myJSONObject, or you have to ensure you pass it when you call `send`, i.e. `send(myJSONObject);`.